# Rollmean returning incorrect values when Zeros present

Tags: r

I'm using `rollmean` to calculate a `28` day rolling average. When a certain days data is zero, it returns a very wrong value.

For example

```
date  OdometerTotal Chronic
08/04  0        -0.000000000406
07/04  7697     5173
07/04  0        -0.00000000000000649
```

This is a line that I'm using to produce the `Chronic` variable

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

Test2 <- Test2 %>% 
group_by(Player.Name) %>% 
mutate('Chronic' = rollmean(OdometerTotal, 28, align="right", na.pad=TRUE, 
na.rm=TRUE))
```

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks

Edit: Does this help?

```
structure(list(Season = c(1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 
1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 
1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 
1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 1516, 
1516), Date = c("2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", 
"2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", 
"2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", 
"2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-06-29", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", 
"2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", 
"2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", 
"2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-01", 
"2015-07-02", "2015-07-02", "2015-07-02", "2015-07-02", "2015-07-03", 
"2015-07-03"), Player.Name = c("Annett Niall", "Baldwin Luke", 
"Barry Darren", "Bower Ryan", "Clegg Justin", "Heathcote Tom", 
"Howard Ben", "Humphreys Perry", "Kirwan Carl", "Kirwan Carl", 
"Kitchener Andrew", "Lewis Sam", "Lewis Sam", "Milasinovich Gareth", 
"Schonert Nick", "Stelling Max", "Taylor Huw", "Annett Niall", 
"Baldwin Luke", "Barry Darren", "Bower Ryan", "Clegg Justin", 
"Hammond Dean", "Heathcote Tom", "Howard Ben", "Humphreys Perry", 
"Kirwan Carl", "Kirwan Carl", "Lewis Sam", "Lewis Sam", "Milasinovich 
Gareth", 
"Schonert Nick", "Stelling Max", "Taylor Huw", "Bower Ryan", 
"Kitchener Andrew", "Milasinovich Gareth", "Taylor Huw", "Annett Niall", 
"Baldwin Luke"), OdometerTotal = c(1320, 1335, 1310, 1295, 1260, 
1253, 1348, 1220, 1379, 1379, 1221, 1271, 1271, 1256, 1275, 1350, 
1311, 1438, 1497, 1299, 1361, 1287, 3053, 1346, 1612, 1543, 1460, 
1460, 1340, 1340, 1162, 1275, 1492, 1371, 4837, 4881, 5008, 5801, 
1719, 1679), Chronic = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), Acute = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), Chronic_weighted = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), Acute_weighted = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), ACR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), ACR_weighted = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA _real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), .Names = c("Season", "Date", "Player.Name", "OdometerTotal", 
"Chronic", "Acute", "Chronic_weighted", "Acute_weighted", "ACR", 
"ACR_weighted"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Player.Name", drop = TRUE, indices = 
list(
c(0L, 17L, 38L), c(1L, 18L, 39L), c(2L, 19L), c(3L, 20L, 
34L), c(4L, 21L), 22L, c(5L, 23L), c(6L, 24L), c(7L, 25L), 
c(8L, 9L, 26L, 27L), c(10L, 35L), c(11L, 12L, 28L, 29L), 
c(13L, 30L, 36L), c(14L, 31L), c(15L, 32L), c(16L, 33L, 37L
)), group_sizes = c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), biggest_group_size = 4L, labels = structure(list(
Player.Name = c("Annett Niall", "Baldwin Luke", "Barry Darren", 
"Bower Ryan", "Clegg Justin", "Hammond Dean", "Heathcote Tom", 
"Howard Ben", "Humphreys Perry", "Kirwan Carl", "Kitchener Andrew", 
"Lewis Sam", "Milasinovich Gareth", "Schonert Nick", "Stelling Max", 
"Taylor Huw")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame", vars = 
"Player.Name", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Player.Name"))
```

Comment: It is very good to include part of your data. This will help us to help you with your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you got more than 28 days data for every player in your data.frame?

Comment: @MKR Yes, there is about 3-4 years worth of data for most players

Comment: `na.pad` is deprecated. You should use `fill` instead.

Comment: fine. May be its worth sharing output of  `dput(head(Test2,40))`

Comment: Added additional data example

Comment: May be using `rollapply` is better option. You can use `partial=TRUE`. You can have a look at my answer.

Comment: There is  a problem with the `dput` output posted -- it gives an error if one tries to copy and paste it into R.  Also, there are no zeros in `OdometerTotal` in the data posted and `rollmean` does not have an `na.rm=` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better option would be to use `rollapply` which got support for `partial` data.

```
library(zoo)

Test2 %>% 
  group_by(Player.Name) %>% 
  mutate(Chronic_cal = rollapply(OdometerTotal, 28, mean, align='right',
         partial = TRUE))
```

Comment: Normally one uses `fill=NA` or `partial=TRUE` but not both.   You either want to fill it with NA values or fill it with partial means.  You can't do both in most circumstances. You could specify `na.rm = TRUE` which was in the code in the question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Valid point. It was overlooked from me.  I will correct my answer. I hope I'm correct in understanding that `rollmean` would have not worked in this case even after removing `na.rm =TRUE` condition.

Comment: The question is not really clear on what the problem is so it's hard to answer.  The question really needs a small example with full input and output shown and expected output.